# Can anyone explain me about recursion in Tower of Hanoi in C language?

Tags: c

```
// Tower of Hanoi
#include <stdio.h>

void towers(int, char, char, char);

int main()
{
    int num;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the number of disks : ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("The sequence of moves involved in the Tower of Hanoi are :\n");
    towers(num, 'A', 'C', 'B');
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void towers(int num, char frompeg, char topeg, char auxpeg)
{
    if (num == 1) {
        printf("\n Move disk 1 from peg %c to peg %c", frompeg, topeg);
        return;
    }
    towers(num - 1, frompeg, auxpeg, topeg);
    printf("\n Move disk %d from peg %c to peg %c", num, frompeg, topeg);
    towers(num - 1, auxpeg, topeg, frompeg);
    getch();
}
```

I ran this code and the output is correct, but I don't understand the recursion of this. Please explain me :} Thank you :]

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable comment for `towers` would be:

> Move *num* discs from peg *frompeg* to peg *topeg* (the remaining peg being *auxpeg*)

Then recursive section says to:

1. Move *num-1* discs from peg *frompeg* to peg *auxpeg* (the remaining peg being *topeg*
2. Move disc from peg *frompeg* to peg *topeg*.
3. Move *num-1* discs from peg *auxpeg* to peg *topeg* (the remaining peg being *frompeg*